# How can I choose $\frak p\unlhd\cal O$ prime so $u\in\cal O^\times$ becomes a $n$-th power (mod $\frak p$)?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

$k$ is an algebraic number field, and $\cal O$ is the ring of integers, $\cal O^\times$ is the set of invertible elements of $\cal O$.

Suppose $u\in\cal O^\times$ is not a $n$-th power.  How can I choose $\frak p\unlhd\cal O$ prime so $u$ becomes a $n$-th power (mod $\frak p$)?

For $u=1$, the answer is a generalization of Dirichlet's Prime Number Theorem: if Fr$_{\frak p}$ fixes $k(\zeta_n)$ then $\zeta_n^{|\cal O/\frak p|}=\zeta_n$, so $\zeta_n^{|(\cal O/\frak p)^\times|} = 1$.  In particular, $n\mid|(\cal O/\frak p)^\times|$, and so 1 is an $n$-th power in $\cal O/\frak p$.

### How to generalize this to arbitrary $u\in\cal O^\times$?

Converse result: when $u = 1$, Lemma 3 in "Le probleme des groupes de congruence pour SL_2" by Serre states that, when $\zeta_n\notin k$, then we can find a prime so 1 is NOT an $n$-th power (mod $\frak p$):

1) Take $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(k(\zeta_n)/k)$ so it acts on $\zeta_n$ non-trivially.

2) Using e.g. Chebotarev's theorem, find a prime $\frak p$ whose Frobenius Fr$_{\frak p}$ acts on $k(\zeta_n)$ same way as $\sigma$.

3) Since Fr$_{\frak p}$ fixes $\cal O/\frak p$ but moves $\zeta_n$, then $\sqrt[n]{1}=\zeta_n\notin\cal O/\frak p$.

This converse would transfer almost verbatim to $\sqrt[n]{u}$ for other $u\in\cal O^\times$; however, the question I asked does not.

Comment: Choose $\mathfrak{p}$ so that Frobenius at $\mathfrak{p}$ is trivial in $\mathrm{Gal}(k(\zeta_n,u^{1/n})/k)$. Then $u$ (and $1$) will be $n$th powers in $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @Epargyreus 
 
Thanks, I actually figured it out minutes before this post. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I can accept it. –